Question about order exchange in double summation with the ceiling of inner variable being the outer variable
When I try to derive the general term formula Cn of the Catalan number by means of generation function, I'm stuck by this equation:

$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty } \sum_{i=0}^{m} f(i,m) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty }
\sum_{m=i}^{\infty} f(i,m)$

Why does the equation above set up?
Is there any theoretical supports or variable substitution tricks?
Is this equation a common sense sort of like '1+1=2'?
PS: I know it's related with Fubini's Theorem, but the summation ranges really confuse me.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Consider the following triangular array where each cell contains $f(i,m)$:
$$
\begin{matrix}
f(0,0) & f(0,1) & f(0,2) & \cdots \\
& f(1,1) & f(1,2) & \cdots \\
& & f(2,2) & \cdots \\
& & & \cdots
\end{matrix}
$$
The sum $ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{m} f(i,m)  $ corresponds to summing over all the elements in the matrix column by column, summing over values of $ i \leq m $, then add up the sums.
The sum $ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=i}^{\infty} f(i,m)$  corresponds to summing over the matrix row by row, summing over values of $ m \geq i $, then add up the sums.
(Of course, this is not a rigorous proof; you must prove that you can exchange the order of summation first.)

Thanks for your reply.It does help.But is the original equation a common sense sort of like '1+1=2'?

No, it is not. 1+1=2 is true by definition. This is true only under certain conditions (so that changing the order of summation does not change the result). @VictorLi
